# How can I build a wsp file for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, wspbuilder

How can I build a wsp file if I have no SharePoint 2013 installed on my local computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install visual studio?  If so, did you install the Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012??  Once you've done that you can create a new SharePoint project and when when you compile it will create the wsp for you and put it in the bin folder.

See here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx and here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123627

Comment: Thanks, but I have no SharePoint 2013 installed on my local PC. I want to copy all required dll to the project and build wsp without using SharePoint. After that I will install wsp to the remote server using a browser.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  I think you need to have SP installed on the same machine that you have visual studio installed to build the wsp.  Maybe with the new app model for certain types of projects you MIGHT be able to get around this but I KNOW for SP 2010 and earlier this was a requirement for all development.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps described in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179924(v=office.15).aspx#o365_napa

After signing up to Office 365 having the NAPA project ready you can start developing.

Comment: Napa provides only SharePoint Apps, wsp is not required for them. I need to build and deploy Web Parts.